# pgAdmin4 Unable to Access Shared Volume in Docker Compose Setup

Tags: docker, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I have the following docker-compose.yml, which successfully runs PostgreSQL and pgadmin4. I have a db backup file in the `shared` folder in the same folder as the .yml. My problem is that pgadmin4 doesn't see the /shared volume. I can see there is a /shared target in Docker Desktop (Mac), so why can't pgadmin see it?

Edit: I mean the directory isn't found in the import process:

[image]

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  DB:
    container_name: pg_container
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: root
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
      POSTGRES_DB: test_db
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./shared:/shared

  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin4_container
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    restart: always
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@admin.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    volumes:
      - ./shared:/shared
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't see"?  This setup looks like you're trying to run a couple of prepackaged images; do you have any of your own source code that's relevant to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pgadmin by design does not let you load arbitrary files from the filesystem. When you're looking at directory `/` in a pgadmin file dialog, that corresponds to the directory `/var/lib/pgadmin/storage/<your_user_name>` (with `@` replaced by `_`) on the pgadmin server.

If you want your local `./shared` directory to be available for restores, you need to mount it inside that storage directory:

```
volumes:
  - ./shared:/var/lib/pgadmin/storage/admin_admin.com/shared
```

After doing this it should show up in the file dialog.